# Hypercore Protocol: Function to get hypercore discovery key from a public key

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, hypercore-protocol

Is there a convenient function to get a hypercore's discovery key from its public key?

I know I can use `myCore.key` and `myCore.discoveryKey` in [hypersdk](https://github.com/datproject/sdk)

But if you just had a key as a hex string (e.g. "778f8d955175c92e4ced5e4f5563f69bfec0c86cc6f670352c457943666fe639"), how would you get the discovery key?

**Is there a convenience function in one of the hypercore-protocol modules?**

Note, [the discovery key is the blake2b-256 hash of the public key](https://web.archive.org/web/20210105154407/https://datprotocol.github.io/how-dat-works/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [`hypercore-crypto`](https://github.com/mafintosh/hypercore-crypto/blob/608ec5b4d0a661575c3cb37a69c13d8f79d3e4ac/index.js#L162) module:

```
const crypto = require('hypercore-crypto')
let publicKey = "778f8d955175c92e4ced5e4f5563f69bfec0c86cc6f670352c457943666fe639"
let discoveryKey = crypto.discoveryKey(Buffer.from(publicKey, 'hex')).toString('hex');
```

Gives a discovery key of:

```
"25a78aa81615847eba00995df29dd41d7ee30f3b01f892209f79b75a57d989e1"
```